# Full screen resolutions with glutGameMode/glutCreateWindow

Tags: opengl, viewport, glut, screen-resolution

I'm trying to set up different full screen resolutions using glut. By that I mean when the application is in full screen on a monitor of say 1920x1080 I want to be able to have a resolution of 1280x720 which just stretches across the whole screen.
Up until now I've been using glutCreateWindow which doesn't do what I want (only draws a portion of the screen):

```
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH );
glutInitWindowSize(1280, 720);
glutCreateWindow(title.c_str());
glutFullScreen();
glViewport(1280, 720);
```

I did some looking around and found glutGameModeString:

```
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH );
glutGameModeString("1280x720:32@60");
glutEnterGameMode();
glViewport(1280, 720);
```

This works as intended but seems to lag really hard for some reason (glutCreateWindow doesn't). I've tried variations on glutGameModeString but it doesn't seem to have any effect. Preferably I'd just like an alternative to glutGameModeString as I can't find much useful information about it other than forum posts.

Comment: Possibly your hardware does not support the given dimensions, so GL has to work hard to scale it up to the physical size.

Comment: Possibly. But it seems to lag no matter what resolution I give it whilst the same resolution works fine with glutCreateWindow